# Open multiple files in vs code (from terminal) from previous terminal command

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

I want to open files in vs code from terminal based on multiple paths given by a previous command like
`find ~+ -iname '*.csproj'`

I tried `find ~+ -iname '*csproj' | code` and `find ~+ -iname '*csproj' | code` but it doesn't work.

PS: I am using Git Bash on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
find ~+ -iname '*csproj' | xargs code
```

or

```
code $(find ~+ -iname '*csproj')
```

The second one only works if the total length of the command does not get too long, that is not too many files are found.